# How to ensure message reception order in MassTransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a saga that has 3 states; Initial, ReceivingRows, Completed -

```
    public static State Initial { get; set; }
    public static State ReceivingRows { get; set; }
    public static State Completed { get; set; }
```

It transitions from Initial to ReceivingRows when it gets a BofMessage (where Bof = Beginning of file). After the BofMessage, it receives a large number of RowMessages where each describes a row in a flat file. Once all RowMessages are sent, an EofMessage is sent and the state changes to Completed. Observe -

```
    static void DefineSagaBehavior()
    {
        Initially(When(ReceivedBof)
            .Then((saga, message) => saga.BeginFile(message))
            .TransitionTo(ReceivingRows));

        During(ReceivingRows, When(ReceivedRow)
            .Then((saga, message) => saga.AddRow(message)));

        During(ReceivingRows, When(ReceivedRowError)
            .Then((saga, message) => saga.RowError(message)));

        During(ReceivingRows, When(ReceivedEof)
            .Then((saga, message) => saga.EndFile(message))
            .TransitionTo(Completed));
    }
```

This works, except sometimes several RowMessages are received *before* the BofMessage! This is regardless of the order that I sent them. This means that the messages will be received and ultimately counted as errors, causing them to be missing from the database or file that I finally write them out to.

As a temporary fix, I add a little sleep timer hack in this method that does all the publishing –

```
    public static void Publish(
        [NotNull] IServiceBus serviceBus,
        [NotNull] string publisherName,
        Guid correlationId,
        [NotNull] Tuple<string, string> inputFileDescriptor,
        [NotNull] string outputFileName)
    {
        // attempt to load offsets
        var offsetsResult = OffsetParser.Parse(inputFileDescriptor.Item1);
        if (offsetsResult.Result != ParseOffsetsResult.Success)
        {
            // publish an offsets invalid message
            serviceBus.Publish<TErrorMessage>(CombGuid.Generate(), publisherName, inputFileDescriptor.Item2);
            return;
        }

        // publish beginning of file
        var fullInputFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(inputFileDescriptor.Item2);
        serviceBus.Publish<TBofMessage>(correlationId, publisherName, fullInputFilePath);

        // HACK: make sure bof message happens before row messages, or else some row messages won't be received
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        // publish rows from feed
        var feedResult = FeedParser.Parse(inputFileDescriptor.Item2, offsetsResult.Offsets);
        foreach (var row in feedResult)
        {
            // publish row message, unaligned if applicable
            if (row.Result != ParseRowResult.Success)
                serviceBus.Publish<TRowErrorMessage>(correlationId, publisherName, row.Fields);
            else
                serviceBus.Publish<TRowMessage>(correlationId, publisherName, row.Fields);
        }

        // publish end of file
        serviceBus.Publish<TEofMessage>(correlationId, publisherName, outputFileName);
    }
```

It’s a 5 second sleep-timer, and is quite an ugly hack. Can anyone inform me why I’m not getting the messages in the order I send them? Can I ensure that these message get sent in the right order if they are unordered by default?

Thank you!

**Please note this is cross-posted from http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss/browse_thread/thread/7bd9518a690db4bb for expedience.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot ensure messages get delivered in any order. You can get close in MT by ensuring there's only one concurrent consumer on the consumer side, I still wouldn't depend on this behaviour (http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/keyideas.html#handlers). This would effectively make your consumer single threaded.